# I want the stage to react every time some changes are made to certain objects. Is there a way to write custom Event?

Tags: actionscript-3

I want the stage to react every time some changes are made to certain objects. Is there a way to write custom Event? I could of course modify this object, but I would like to know if there is any more `OOP` way to do it. And events ARE `OOP`, ain't they?

Comment: What objects? React how? More Information and code please.

Comment: Well, objects of class that extends MovieClip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say you have a property `count` in some class. Easiest way is to generate setter and getter for this property and inside the setter to dispatch some custom event.

```
protected var _count:Number;
public function get count():Number
{
    return _count;
}
public function set count(value:Number):void
{
    _count = value;
    dispatchEvent(new CountEvent(CountEvent.COUNT_CHANGED, value, true));
}
```

This is the custom event class:

```
public class CountEvent extends Event
{
    public static const COUNT_CHANGED:String = "countChanged";

    public var data:Object;

    public function CountEvent(type:String, data:Object, bubbles:Boolean=false, cancelable:Boolean=false)
    {
        super(type, bubbles, cancelable);
        this.data = data;
    }

    override public function clone():Event
    {
        return new CountEvent(type, data, bubbles, cancelable);
    }
}
```

Note that if you need the value of the property and don't have reference to the object itself, you can create a data-object event. In order for this kind of custom event to work properly you need to override the clone method, which is used every time the event is re-dispatched.

If you are looking for more advanced way of "observing" something is by using some custom code, e.g. 
http://code.google.com/p/flit/source/browse/trunk/flit/src/obecto/utility/observe/Observe.as?r=190

In either way you must decide whether you want to modify your class by adding a dispatcher (if your class is not a **EventDispatcher** subclass) and dispatch an event or use some other techniques. Another way is to make the property `[Bindable]` and use a binding between your property and some function to watch if something changes.

Comment: so i need to modify the class i want to listen to?

Comment: can you be a little more specific about your last sentences?

Comment: In order to dispatch event from the class you need to watch, this class must extends EventDispatcher or have a reference to an object that extends it so it can dispatch the event. About the binding stuff i mentioned - you can use the Flex framework BindingUtils class 
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/binding/utils/BindingUtils.html
in order to watch when something happens to your property.

Comment: No, it prolly won't work. If you are using plain AS3 without the Flex SDK and only the Flash IDE (not Flash builder) the only option will be the custom event fired from the setter.

Answer (score 2):

A custom event class can be written like this:

```
public class MyEvent extends Event
{
    private var evtData:Object;

    public function MyEvent(type:String, data:Object)
    {
        super(type);
        //fill this.evtData here
    }

    override public function clone():Event
    {
         return new MyEvent(type, evtData);
    }
}
```

then dispatch this event by:

```
dispatch(new MyEvent("someName", obj))
```

and catch it like

```
myObj.addEventListener("someName", handleMyEvent);
function handleMyEvent(evt:MyEvent):void
{
    //do something with evt
}
```

Comment: It's also a good idea to set up your event names as `public static const` in your `MyEvent` class. I do it merely to prevent code mistakes (like typos on the event name). eg. `public static const SOME_NAME:String = "someName";` and `myObj.addEventListener(MyEvent.SOME_NAME, handleMyEvent);`

Comment: where should i check out for the chages? for example, i'm waiting for `m` to become more than 100. what will that look like?